# Does the word "fold" in the following context mean "times"?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm reading a book and I saw there a sentence with the word "fold" but I am not sure about the meaning of this word in the context:

> Overall, glia outnumber neurons in the mammalian brain 10-to 50-**fold**.

Does this "fold" mean like "times"?

Comment: Not exactly. See this definition of "fold change" on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_change.

Comment: Exactly. Refer to [the definition in Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/-fold).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. When something changes from 1 to 100, that's a hundredfold. 300 to 900 is threefold.

Generally, if a number is followed with -fold, it means [number]-times.

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.  Saying something is X-fold is saying it is 2^x times.  Think "folding paper."  How many parts do you have if you fols a piece of paper three times? The answer is 8.  Thus 3-fold is 8-times.

I talk with scientists frequently who are writing studies who don't know the difference between the two words, so you find them used interchangeably.  I always point it out when I review a study, but given a moment of analysis, I can normally tell what they really mean.  Having said that, there is ZERO excuse for allowing this error to continue.

If X is 10, then a "3 times" increase makes the result 30, while a "3 fold" increase makes the result 80.  The difference is not trivial.  Quality control and editors should know the difference; obviously they do not.

Comment: Sorry, this is an incorrect interpretation. See any dictionary ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tenfold), [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenfold). [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tenfold), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenfold)). See this [english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56350/is-the-word-tenfold-a-misnomer) question.

Comment: Is there any kind of citation for this? I would love to be able to refute my thinking on this.